# Three.js panorama weird render with canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js

I got a problem with the canvas renderer of the three.js, I used the panorama example with my own pics, but the geometry does not seems to be good. Tried to play a lot with different parameters, like texture canvas size, size of the box, ... but no good result sadly.

Here is the sample : http://prods.mightyprods.com/Three/panoramasimple.php

Tried the webgl sample, it works well : http://prods.mightyprods.com/Three/skybox.html

I really need to work with canvas element, because of compatibility... any idea of what's wrong with this ?

Thanks by advance for any help.

PS : sorry for my bad english...

Comment: I am curious to see if you can get this working. I have had similar troubles when viewing my demos with the Canvas renderer. Seems that regardless of what FOV I use and such I still get some warping of textures and different viewpoints and such. It may just be a limitation of using textures with the Canvas renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed a limitation of `CanvasRenderer`. You can try adding more subdivisions to the cube or decreasing the camera fov.

Comment: I tried to add more subdivisions it works, but it's more ressource consuming, but I tried also many values for the camera fov, from 0 to 180, and did not saw any visible changes, what should be the best range for this ? I rode that fov is the vertical angle of the camera, am I right ?

Comment: Ok tried to modify the fov dynamicaly but without success but while creating camera it's ok, so I used a 45° fov and it's better, thanks for your help.